# Why does "this.myFunction" not work when calling a function inside an object?

Tags: javascript, oop, this

Here are two samples of code. The first one does not work and the second one does, though I'm completely at a loss as to why. Can someone explain this?

[I'm writing a simple game using a bit of jQuery to be played in a webkit browser (packaged with Titanium later).]

In the first example, Firebug tells me that "this.checkCloud" is not a function.

```
function Cloud(){

    this.checkCloud = function(){
      alert('test');            
    }

    $("#"+this.cloudName).click(function(){
        this.checkCloud();
    });

}
```

...but then this works:

```
function Cloud(){

    this.checkCloud = function(){
      alert('test');            
    }

    var _this = this;

    $("#"+this.cloudName).click(function(){
        _this.checkCloud();
    });

}
```

This one works perfect.

Why does the first one not work? Is it because "this.checkCloud" is inside of the anonymous function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in this example:

```
$("#"+this.cloudName).click(function(){
        this.checkCloud();
    });
```

`this` referrers to the element selected(jquery object).

what you can do is use private functions

```
var checkCloud = function(){
      alert('test');            
    }
```

this way you can simply call it inside your anonymous function

```
$("#"+this.cloudName).click(function(){
            checkCloud();
        });
```

Comment: So in JavaScript doing "var" is like making something Private if it's in a function. That makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

That is because the meaning of `this` can potentially change each time you create a new scope via a function. The meaning of `this` depends on how the function is invoked (and the rules can be insanely complicated). As you discovered, the easy solution is to create a second variable to which you save `this` in the scope where `this` has the expected/desired value, and then reuse the variable rather than `this` to refer to the same object in new function scopes where `this` could be different.

Comment: *"`this` trefers to the enclosing scope...`this` in the innermost function refers to the innermost function"* Although it may (or may not) change with each function, it doesn't refer to the enclosing scope, nor does it refer to the function itself (unless you've made it do so). We don't know *how* `Cloud()` is being invoked, so we don't really know what `this` is in that function.

Comment: @patrick, good point. I added some additional information about it. I realize this might still not be 100% correct, but it is a useful way to think about it.

Comment: Yeah, `this` is such an odd subject in javascript. There's at least a  half dozen different things to consider that could alter the `this` value.

Comment: Thanks for the understanding, but after thinking about it some more, my explanation was rather off... made it more accurate.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function Cloud(){

    this.checkCloud = function(){
      alert('test');            
    }

    var func = this.checkCloud;

    $("#" + this.cloudName).click(function(){
         func();
     });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you assign an even listener to an element, jQuery makes sure that `this` will refer to the element. But when you create the `_this` variable, you're creating a closure that jQuery couldn't mess with, even if it wanted to.

Comment: Has nothing to do with jQuery, in particular, but rather JavaScript in general.

Comment: @Michael: jQuery manually sets the value of `this` to refer to the element that invoked the handler. If `Cloud()` is not invoked as a constructor, and we made the inner function just a typical named function, and invoked it, the code would work because `this` in both functions would refer to `window` (unless you're in strict mode). **Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/9NmPF/1/